# Trying to launch jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to open jupyter notebook and having trouble launching jupyter notebook from anaconda. When launching from navigation and anaconda prompt this message is displayed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in  from notebook.notebookapp import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'`

Using python 3.11
pip 23.2.1
jupyter notebook 6.5.4
have tried uninstalling and reinstaling anaconda
tried uninstalling jupyter notebook
checking which kernel jupyter is using
creating a new path and launching it that way (no luck)

Comment: have you tried using jupyter without anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Install the app separately, type `conda install jupyter` in your command prompt and launch again